# How to sort/find tags based on used & votes?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

I want to sort/list tags on Ask Ubuntu based on use. For example:

- used this week (no. of questions tagged this week)
- used this month/year (no. of questions tagged this month/year)

Another example for sorting tags:

- votes on tag in this week/month/year

Comment: You explain the what, but not the why. Why do you want to have this data?

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

- used this week (no. of questions tagged this week), for questions tagged [tag] created during the week from June 23 to 29

  ```
  [tag] created:2014-06-23..2014-06-29 is:q
  ```
- used this month/year (no. of questions tagged this month/year), for questions created a specific month/year:

  ```
  [tag] created:201406 is:q
  [tag] created:2014 is:q
  ```

Up till here is pretty easy yet complex. `[tag]` is to narrow the search to a specific tag; `created:` is to specify when was the post created (you have `active` also); the date format is YYYY-MM-DD and doesn't have shortcuts, like "today", "50 week", etc.; `is:q` is to prevent you from finding answers.

> votes on tag in this week/month/year

This would require you to query the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).